# Is there any online translation of grhya and shrauta sutras?

Tags: scripture, translation-request, grihya-sutra

I m looking for some translation of these sutras preferably with actual sanskrit verse.

There are grhya sutras on sacred texts website but various sutras are combined together and i m not able to find some chapter.

English or hindi translations would be okay

Comment: Which Grihya sutras or Shrauta sutras? Be specific and limit the question to either one of them to prevent multiple partial answers.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma the more the better it is

Comment: More partial answers is not good. Getting more _complete_  and specific answers is good. Otherwise, it makes the question too broad.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma But it will be helpful for many in future.

Comment: It will be helpful but specific questions are more suitable. If you want to put all of them at a place, Make a Community wiki. So, are you thinking of making it? Those are fit for list questions like these. Otherwise, it may result in incomplete answers and partial answers. However, it good to specify which Sutra are you looking e.g Apasthambha and makig another post for Srauta Sutras instead of combining with this Grihya Sutras.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma it will make too.many questions if i make separate question on every grhya sutra. Anyways you can vote for closing if you want .